# Can't find Docker Plugin on Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to build an image using docker.
Connecting with Jenkins, then moving to

**Manage Jenkins > Plugins management**, I don't found `Docker plugin` there.

Also, I tried **Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration**, I can't see `Docker` Part as displayed bellow.

[image]

Could you please tell me what I missed ?.
Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add that plugin using the download of `docker-build-publish-1.3.2.hpi`.
Then you have to restart Jenkins.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Download externally docker plugin which is .hpi file and place that file under /JENKINS_HOME/plugins folder

Answer (score 0):

You could go to Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> search for docker in the search bar to the top right corner -> install docker.

You may choose to restart jenkins after the installation is complete. Once the docker plugin is fully installed, head over to Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> at the bottom you'll have docker available.